# How to parse SQL operators using FParsec

Tags: fparsec, sql-parser

I'm parsing SQL expressions and have been looking at [this example](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/blob/156cbd751fac67ca7cc04cf661710f1f90a216a5/Samples/Calculator/calculator.fs). So far I'm focused on boolean operators like `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`, `IN` and `NOT IN`. The first four seem easy to implement, however I'm not sure what to do with `NOT IN`:

```ml
type BinaryExpr = {left: SqlExpr; right: SqlExpr}
and SqlExpr = 
    And of BinaryExpr 
    | Or of BinaryExpr 
    | Not of SqlExpr 
    | In of BinaryExpr 
    | NotIn of BinaryExpr
    | Identifier of string

let parser =
    let opp = OperatorPrecedenceParser<SqlExpr, unit, unit>()
    let ws = spaces
    let ws1 = nextCharSatisfiesNot isLetter >>. ws
    let expr = opp.ExpressionParser
    
    opp.TermParser <- identifier <|> expr
    let buildAnd x y = And { left = x; right = y }
    let buildOr x y = Or { left = x; right = y }
    let buildIn x y = In { left = x; right = y }
    let buildNotIn x y = NotIn { left = x; right = y }
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("OR", ws1, 1, Associativity.Left, buildOr))
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("AND", ws1, 2, Associativity.Left, buildAnd))
    opp.AddOperator(PrefixOperator("NOT", ws1, 3, false, Not))
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("IN", ws1, 4, Associativity.None, buildIn))
    opp.AddOperator(InfixOperator("NOT IN", ws1, 4, Associativity.None, buildNotIn))
    
    ws >>. expr .>> eof
```

What I want is:

- Handle more than one space between "NOT" and "IN"
- Parse "NOT IN" as a binary operator

Currently I'm failing in the first point.

I'm assuming that `NOT IN` is semantically a binary operator and because of that I have created the `NotIn` type variant.